# How can I detect resizeStop event on Kendo UI Window?

Tags: kendo-ui

The title explains it all...

I need to perform a custom action when I know a user has finished resizing, but from what I can find in the Kendo UI documentation there is no event for this accessible to me other that 'resize' which I cannot use as is.

Perhaps i just missed the event?

if not:

Is there a way to use the 'resize' event to determine that a user has stopped resizing?

Comment: I think that the question is actually define what means _stop_ resizing. Does it mean that the user did not resize for certain period of time? If so, you might define a `resize` event handler that takes note of the time that was executed and start a timeout. If a new `resize` event arrives you restart the timeout. If the timeout expires then you have the _stop resizing_ event.

Comment: Stopped resizing I would define as a user was once resizing and has now completed said action.

And the method you described above wont work as 'resize' is only called when a change has occured in the widget size, this means that a user could click to resize the widget then not move the cursor, which wont serve a resize event therefore making the timer fire prematurely.

Comment: Just for a question of completeness and making sure that this question readers understand it: `resize` event **is not** `fired` when you `click` on the resize corner **but** when you move the mouse. So if you click to resize the widget but do not move it, you have no resize event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my answer thus far:

**Mine differs slightly due to architectural needs, but here's a general solution**

```
var isResizing = false;
var wndw = $(element).kendoWindow({
                // .....
                resize: OnResize,
                // .....
            }).data('kendoWindow');

function onResize() {
    isResizing = true;
}

$('body').on('mouseup', '.k-window', function() {
    if(isResizing){
        // **Your 'Stopped' code here**
        isResizing = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have edited your code for adding a `.` to `k-window` selector. I've made some additional (cosmetic) changes since SO does not allow just add a `.` as edition and in this case that `.` is really important

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using underscore.js [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)? I have used it successfully to only trigger then change after the resize events have stopped coming for a certain period (in the case below 300ms). This does add a small delay to captureing the end, but if like me you just want to store the final size then that works fine. Here is the version of the code above but using underscore debounce:

```
  var wndw = $(element).kendoWindow({
            // .....
            resize: _.debounce( this.hasResized, 300)
            // .....
        }).data('kendoWindow');

  //This is called at the end of a resize operation (using _.debounce)
  function hasResized (args) {
        // ** Your code here **
  };
```

Hope that helps.