# Is that possible to detect the header of Kendo being changed?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

If user resizes the Kendo Grid header `$("#myTable .k-header")`, is that possible to detect it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983352/how-can-i-detect-resizestop-event-on-kendo-ui-window

Comment: nah, not really bruh!

Comment: Yes, there's a `columnResize` event.

Comment: @ataravati how to use it?

Comment: Post your grid code so I can show you how to use it.

Comment: @AlexMcManns - by "bruh", do you mean brunette?  but even that assumption is wrong.

Comment: when I inctantiate my kendoGrid, I stick it inside, like: `$("#myTable").kendoGrid({
columnResize: alert("TEST")
})`, right?

Comment: @ataravati but it fires only once, and when I resize the column, nothing happens.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnResize

Comment: found it, you just have to stick it inside the function!!

Comment: @ataravati thank you sir, for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in their documentation here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-columnResize, it would look something like this:

```
$('#my-grid').kendoGrid({
 columnResize: function(e) {
    console.log(e.column.field, e.newWidth, e.oldWidth);
  }
});
```

or if you wanted to bind to it after initialization, it would be something like this:

```
var grid = $('#my-grid').data('kendoGrid');
grid.bind('columnResize', function(e) {
    console.log(e.column.field, e.newWidth, e.oldWidth);
});
```